# Confusion about init_task (pid 0 or pid 1?)

Tags: linux, kernel, init

I'm playing with the Linux kernel, and one thing that I don't understand is the pid of the `init_task` task.

As far as I know, there are two special pids: pid 0 for the idle/swapper task, and pid 1 for the init task.

Every online resource (e.g. [one](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1174004), [two](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2010-January/007015.html)) I could find say that the `init_task` task represents the swapper task, i.e. it should have pid 0.

But when I print all the pids using the `for_each_process` macro, which starts from `init_task`, I get pid 1 as the first process. I don't get pid 0 at all. Which means that `init_task` has pid 1, and that it's the init task (?!).

Please help me resolve this confusion.

P.S. the kernel version is 2.4.

Comment: For the Holy Writings: `#define for_each_process(p) \ for (p = &init_task ; (p = next_task(p)) != &init_task ; )`. You *must* see `init_task` somewhere... And yes, `init_task` *is* the swapper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for my confusion was the tricky definition of the `for_each_task` macro:

```
#define for_each_task(p) \
        for (p = &init_task ; (p = p->next_task) != &init_task ; )
```

Even though it seems that `p` starts from `init_task`, it actually starts from `init_task.next_task` because of the assignment in the condition.

So `for_each_task(p) { /* ... */ }` could be rewritten as:

```
p = init_task.next_task;
while(p != &init_task)
{
    /* ... */
    p = p->next_task;
}
```

As it can be seen, the swapper process is not part of the iteration.